# How do I move files to a new directory based on their name in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to linux and need to solve a problem where I have a directory with many files in the following pattern:

```
./data/xaa_basic
./data/xaa_extra
./data/xab_basic
./data/xab_extra
./data/xac_basic
./data/xac_extra
... (+400)
```

How do I create a script to organize them into subdirectories as follows?

```
./data/1/xaa_basic
./data/1/xaa_extra
./data/2/xab_basic
./data/2/xab_extra
./data/3/xac_basic
./data/3/xac_extra
... (+400)
```

Comment: It depends.  Is the intermediate subdirectory just a one-up counter, or is there some relationship between the prefix of the file and the subdirectory it is to be placed into?  What directory will `xwz_basic` need to go in?  Does it matter?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Just a one-up counter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like (assuming your current working directory is the toplevel `data`):

```
i=0; for f in x{a..d}{a..d}; do mkdir -p $((++i)); mv ${f}_{extra,basic} $i; done
```

Tweak the bounds to match the files you have.  You might also just use a more shotgun approach and do:

```
 i=0; for f in x*_extra; do mkdir -p $((++i)); mv "${f%_extra}"_{extra,basic} $i; done
```

If you have any files of the form xxx_basic that do not have a matching `_extra` file, they will get skipped.  Modify as needed.